# Highlight function names in a string (PHP)

Tags: php, preg-replace, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know, how to highlight function names in a string containing code?

For example I have to following string:

```
$text = "t <- ind.t.test$statistic[[1]
df <- ind.t.test$parameter[[1]]
r <- sqrt(t^2/(t^2+df))
round(r)";
```

Now I'd like to replace the function `sqrt()` by

```
<font color='red'>sqrt</font>(t^2...
```

I've tried it with:- `preg_replace()`,

but did not manage to get it right.

Thank you!

Comment: show your attempt with `preg_replace()`

Comment: `preg_replace('/(sqrt|round)/', '<span class="highlight">\0</span>', $text);` and then add a css class for .highlight

Comment: Thank you, for your help! The Problem is, it should not only work for the functions mentioned in the string above (sqrt, round) but for **any** function name.

Comment: you can add as many as you like just keep pipe separating them, or try and find a library that will do this for you for whatever language that is

Comment: Here's a very naive attempt... `preg_replace('/(\w+)\(/', '<span class="highlight">\1</span>', $text);`

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work. However function names can also contain points, underscores etc. I will try to fix that myself now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.Just the ticket.

```
$text = "t <- ind.t.test$statistic[[1]
df <- ind.t.test$parameter[[1]]
r <- sqrt(t^2/(t^2+df))
round(r)";

$st2="<font color='red'>sqrt</font>(t^2...";
$match= preg_replace("/\s(\w+)\S(?=\()/",$st2,$text);
echo $match;
;
```